# Display vertical HTML5 range in a table

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make a HTML5 range appear vertical inside a table, but I can't figure out how to do it. In fact, when the range is outside the table, no problem, but when it's inside, impossible to make it vertical ! Annoying...

```
<table>
<tr>
<div class="slide"><th><input type="range" min="0" max="100" id="slider1"></th></div>
</tr>
</table>
```

and css :

```
slide {
    -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
    -moz-transfrom: rotate(270deg);
}
```

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/p4Yje/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have four issues with your code:

1. Your markup is invalid. You cannot have a `div` element as the immediate child of a `tr` element.
2. You CSS class-selector is wrong. You are missing a `.` at the beginning of it.
3. You should apply the styling to the range element, not to a wrapping div.
4. The `th` element should only be used for columns within the table-head `thead` element. Judging by your example code, that is not the case, then you should use the `td` element instead.

**Markup:**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input class="slide" type="range" min="0" max="100" id="slider1"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.slide {
    -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
    -moz-transfrom: rotate(270deg);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WU2vA/1/)

Comment: Great ! Thanks Christofer !